# Visualforce IF Statement

Tags: visualforce, email-template, conditional

The code below is a section in a VF email template that should conditionally output a link to all the Legal Request records where Request Type == Sales AND Service Type == New Business, but something is wrong with the syntax, because I keep getting errors on Save.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
<table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color: #0099CC; color: #FFFFFF">
                        <b>Legal Request Number</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Legal_Requests__r}" var="legalRequest">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {!IF(AND(legalRequest.Request_Type__c == 'Sales', legalRequest.Service_Type__c == 'New Business'), <a href ="https://fico--dev1.cs30.my.salesforce.com/{!legalRequest.Id}">{!legalRequest.Name}</a> , false)}
                            </td>                                                          
                        </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't allowed to use angle-brackets inside a merge expression. Why not just use an apex:outputLink?

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!legalRequest.Id}" rendered={!AND(legalRequest.Request_Type__c == 'Sales', legalRequest.Service_Type__c == 'New Business')} >
     {!legalRequest.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to VF.  Can you post an example?

Comment: I updated my answer with a better example

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: if the link doesn't behave quite right, you may need to replace the 'value' portion of the tag with `value="{!URLFOR($Action.Legal_Request__c.View, legalRequest.Id)}"`